# How does Spring MVC convert @RequestParam values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm new to the Spring Framework, and as a symptom, I want to keep my adoption of its Web MVC portions as simple as possible, so I'm using the annotation functions to work with Spring. In the past, I've used: 
`int value = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("numberValue"))` 
to pull values from parameters - explicitly converting the String returned by `getParameter()`.
 Helpfully, I've noticed that when I use Spring's  terminology:
`@RequestParameter("numberValue") int numVal`
the conversion is handled automatically. This is nice, but a "black box" to me. I tried looking at questions on here or in the Spring documentation, but all that information deals with custom conversions (like Converter) for objects or formatting issues. All I want to know is how Spring handles primitive type conversions for `@RequestParam` by default.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I've noticed that when I use Spring's terminology:
>   @RequestParameter("numberValue") int numVal the conversion is handled
>   automatically.

Here you are looking for Type Conversion

As per spring documentation given on this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion)

> String-based values extracted from the request including request
>   parameters, path variables, request headers, and cookie values may
>   need to be converted to the target type of the method parameter or
>   field (e.g., binding a request parameter to a field in an
>   @ModelAttribute parameter) they’re bound to. If the target type is not
>   String, Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type. All
>   simple types such as int, long, Date, etc. are supported.

Comment: Maybe offtopic:What if I forgot to pass the paramerter and I'm trying to store it in a primitive. I think as a rule of thumb we should always store params in String or any wrapper class.

Comment: You can perform arbitrary conversions if you implement [your own converter](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions). It is enough to implement the `Converter` interface and annotate the class with `@Component` (if you're using component scanning). Spring takes care of the rest.