# java8 spring 4.2.5 can't convert to java.util.Optional

Tags: spring, java-8

I have a problem with spring 4.2.5 and java8.

Trying to write simple rest:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "raw2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<String> getTest(@RequestParam Optional<String> p) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But keep getting errors:

```
2016-04-05 20:51:41,436 DEBUG [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/internal/raw2]
2016-04-05 20:51:41,438 DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] Mapping [/internal/raw2] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [com.test.con] and 1 interceptor
2016-04-05 20:51:41,440 DEBUG [o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] Last-Modified value for [/internal/raw2] is: -1
2016-04-05 20:51:41,453 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils] No property editor [java.util.OptionalEditor] found for type java.util.Optional according to 'Editor' suffix convention   
2016-04-05 20:51:41,453 DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.a.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [com.test.con]: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type  [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
2016-04-05 20:51:41,454 DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [com.test.con]: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
2016-04-05 20:51:41,454 DEBUG [o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [com.test.con]: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
2016-04-05 20:51:41,454 WARN  [o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Optional]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Shouldn't your RequestParam have a value attribute defined, i.e. which request parameter it binds to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804388/how-does-spring-mvc-convert-requestparam-values

Comment: This may sound stupid, but having someone ask me such questions helped me more than once in the past so... Are you completely positive that you're using this version of Spring? E.g. for maven and linux/osx the most simple and reliable (I never fully trust IDEs on these things) way to check this would be `mvn dependency:tree | grep -E "$|spring-"`.

Comment: it's 4.2.5 100%. If I remove Optional..and just leave String. Everything works as expected. But I want optional...it should work starting from spring 4.1...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tag in XML. This will make sure that convertors are available